# Is it possible to have an admin inline without original data being shown?

Tags: python, django

In the django admin I have a model with an inline. I would like to be able to only show "add new" lines for the inline, and not show any preexisting, original data in the table belonging to the inline. Is this possible? I have tried every combination of `max_num` and `extra`, and it always shows existing table data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not possible with a simple switch in the `InlineAdmin`
subclass. But I can think of a small "hack" that achieves the same:

Use the `template` attribute on your `InlineAdmin` to specify a custom template
to render your inlines. Now copy the original template you want to use into
your custom template (e.g. copy
`django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html`). Look at the
source and find the line with `{% for inline_admin_form in
inline_admin_formset %}` and insert `{% if not inline_admin_form.original %}`
after it. Also insert `{% endif %}` right before the closing `{% endfor %}`
tag.

This method actualy just hides the output of the inlines. So its still possible
to modify them by passing raw POST data to the page, for example with `curl`
(but the "attacker" [read: admin user ;-)] must know django and how it
generates the fieldnames in formsets).

The `tabular.html` might look now like this:

```
{% load i18n %}
<div class="inline-group">
  <div class="tabular inline-related {% if forloop.last %}last-related{% endif %}">
{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.management_form }}
<fieldset class="module">
   <h2>{{ inline_admin_formset.opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</h2>
   {{ inline_admin_formset.formset.non_form_errors }}
   <table>
     <thead><tr>
     {% for field in inline_admin_formset.fields %}
       {% if not field.is_hidden %}
         <th {% if forloop.first %}colspan="2"{% endif %}>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
        {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
     {% if inline_admin_formset.formset.can_delete %}<th>{% trans "Delete?" %}</th>{% endif %}
     </tr></thead>

     <tbody>
     {% for inline_admin_form in inline_admin_formset %}
     {% if not inline_admin_form.original %}
        {% if inline_admin_form.form.non_field_errors %}
        <tr><td colspan="{{ inline_admin_form.field_count }}">{{ inline_admin_form.form.non_field_errors }}</td></tr>
        {% endif %}
        <tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %} {% if inline_admin_form.original or inline_admin_form.show_url %}has_original{% endif %}">

        <td class="original">
          {% if inline_admin_form.original or inline_admin_form.show_url %}<p>
          {% if inline_admin_form.original %} {{ inline_admin_form.original }}{% endif %}
          {% if inline_admin_form.show_url %}<a href="../../../r/{{ inline_admin_form.original_content_type_id }}/{{ inline_admin_form.original.id }}/">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>{% endif %}
            </p>{% endif %}
          {% if inline_admin_form.has_auto_field %}{{ inline_admin_form.pk_field.field }}{% endif %}
          {{ inline_admin_form.fk_field.field }}
          {% spaceless %}
          {% for fieldset in inline_admin_form %}
            {% for line in fieldset %}
              {% for field in line %}
                {% if field.is_hidden %} {{ field.field }} {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endspaceless %}
        </td>

        {% for fieldset in inline_admin_form %}
          {% for line in fieldset %}
            {% for field in line %}
              <td class="{{ field.field.name }}">
              {{ field.field.errors.as_ul }}
              {{ field.field }}
              </td>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if inline_admin_formset.formset.can_delete %}
          <td class="delete">{% if inline_admin_form.original %}{{ inline_admin_form.deletion_field.field }}{% endif %}</td>
        {% endif %}

        </tr>

     {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
   </table>

</fieldset>
  </div>

  {# <ul class="tools"> #}
  {#   <li><a class="add" href="">Add another {{ inline_admin_formset.opts.verbose_name|title }}</a></li> #}
  {# </ul> #}

</div>
```

Comment: I think there would be cleaner ways to do this in Python code, by making a BaseInlineFormset subclass that never displays existing data and overriding the proper method on your admin.ModelInline subclass to make it use your formset class.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I haven't thought about that. Maybe I have to less experience with formsets. The subclass approach is ofcourse much cleaner and not so much a "hack".

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
```

and then

```
class ModelNameInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ModelNameInlineFormSet, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.queryset = ModelName.objects.none()

class ModelNameInline(admin.TabularInline):
    formset = inlineformset_factory(ParentModelName, ModelName, 
                                    formset=ModelNameInlineFormSet)
```