# How to omit object name from Django's TabularInline admin view?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using Django's `TabularInline` admin view to edit category objects related to a main topic object, as shown here:

[image]

Is there a way to **not** show the rendered names of the objects ("General Questions", "Media Handling and Margins", etc. in this example), *without* creating a custom admin template?  In other words, I just want to show a clean grid of input fields.

I found the relevant rendering code [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html), at this fragment:

```
   ...
        <td class="original">
          {% if inline_admin_form.original or inline_admin_form.show_url %}<p>
          {% if inline_admin_form.original %} {{ inline_admin_form.original }}{% endif %}
          {% if inline_admin_form.show_url %}<a href="../../../r/{{ inline_admin_form.original_content_type_id }}/{{ inline_admin_form.original.id }}/">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>{% endif %}
            </p>{% endif %}
   ...
```

Is there a short, clever way to omit the `{{ inline_admin_form.original }}` or have it return Null?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2094140

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought I'd chime in that editing your template is going to be the easiest.

I tried iterating over the formsets in `render_change_form` but unfortunately, the major problem is that `InlineAdminForm`s are constructed dynamically upon iteration in the template so you can't just set `inlineadminform.original = None` or modify the context.

They don't even exist until assigned a variable in the template.

```
# InlineAdminFormset
def __iter__(self):
    for form, original in zip(self.formset.initial_forms, self.formset.get_queryset()):
        yield InlineAdminForm(self.formset, form, self.fieldsets,
            self.opts.prepopulated_fields, original, self.readonly_fields,
            model_admin=self.model_admin)
```

and the only easily non-hackishly accessible hook we have there is overriding `InlineAdminFormset.formset.get_queryset()` which breaks other things.

Can I [share some code](https://gist.github.com/839996) nobody should ever really look at but works and makes me crack up laughing? I owe you one payne. Hope I can get to sleep tonight.

Comment: Thank you!  I suspected that editing the template would be the real answer.

Answer (score 67):

@sjaak-schilperoort Nice one! CSS is indeed the 'trick' to use. Example of the class `Foo` which has `Bar` as inline.

`static/css/hide_admin_original.css`:

```
td.original p {
  visibility: hidden
}

.inline-group .tabular tr.has_original td {
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

`admin.py`:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [ BarInline, ]
  class Media:
    css = { "all" : ("css/hide_admin_original.css",) }

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Comment: change `padding-top` to 5px to be consistent with rows without has_original

Comment: this works well in Django 1.11, just use 10px for padding-top.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will hide the edit button when show_change_link is set to True (the link is within the paragraph and the text does not have its own wrapping element...)

Answer (score 4):

I took a slightly different approach. It's a little hackish. This replaces the "original" string with a blank string, so the td for class=original still gets rendered leaving a gap above the edit boxes.

I like the CSS solution better (I had to use 'padding-top: 5px;' to get the rendering right).

#### models.py:

```
class Model(model.Model):
  general_questions = models.TextField()
  _hide = False

  def __unicode__(self):
    if _hide:
      return ''
```

#### admin.py:

```
class ModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model
    extra = 0

class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [ModelInline, ]

  def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
    for formset in context['inline_admin_formsets']:
      qs = formset.formset.queryset
        for model_obj in qs:
          model_obj._hide = True

  return super(ModelAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I like this approach but it does work on my Django 2.1.7.

Comment: nice hack works on Django 2.2.5 had to add an "else" condition for "TypeError: __str__ returned non-string"  error

Comment: ok after testing it leads to inheritance issues i tried @Rick van  it also works fine on django 2.2.5

Answer (score 2):

You could use css to hide the paragraph

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking to hide the header on a `StackedInline`, I used [Rick´s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5556813/1850606) but adding this css:

```
div.inline-related h3{
   visibility: hidden;
   height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to do so is by adding a css to the template file, the answer by Rick van der Zwet is the best one

Answer (score 0):

Simple and clean ^^"

```
def __str__(self):
    return ""
```