# Remove title from TabularInline in admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When I create a TabularInline in my Django's admin panel, it displays a title per record. How can I change this title? How can I delete this title?

I include a screenshot below. The title I am referring to is here ExportLookupTableElement object. The lines without that title are the extra fields to add new ones. I want the entire table to look like this.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5556813

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove this title by overriding Django's admin css:

1. Create `css/custom_admin.css` in your static directory with following code:

```css
.inline-group .tabular tr.has_original td {
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.original {
    display: none;
}
```

2. Edit your `admin.py` file to include this extra css for ModelAdmin that you want to remove title:

```python
class TestDetailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TestDetail

class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('css/custom_admin.css', )     # Include extra css
        }
    inlines = [TestDetailInline]
```

[image: example django admin after override]

Or you can override css for all admin pages by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357204).

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  In Django 2.1, I had to use '<app_name>/custom.css' rather than 'css/custom.css'

Comment: Works like a charm! I had to tweak the path to static as well, but I guess that's just a project setting.

Answer (score 1):

Based on nattster's answer I did this:

edit/create `templates/admin/base_site.html`:

```html
    {% extends "admin/base.html" %}
    {% block extrastyle %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "admin/css/admin_overrides.css" %}" />
    {% endblock %}
```

create `admin/css/admin_overrides.css`:

```css
    /* StackedInline */
    .inline-group .hide-title h3 b, .inline-group .hide-title h3 .inline_label {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    /* TabularInline */
    .inline-group .tabular .hide-title .original > p {
        display: none;
    }

    .inline-group .tabular .hide-title tr.has_original td {
        padding-top: 8px;
    }
```

Now you can hide the title for some inlines while keep it for others:

```python
    class TestTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
        classes = ("hide-title",)
        ...
    
    class TestStackedInline(admin.StackedInline):
        classes = ("hide-title",)
        ...
```

Answer (score -2):

If you can afford it for the purposes of your inlined model, returning an empty string from its `__str__` method has exactly the same effect as solutions provided above. The title element is still in the HTML, but no longer takes up any visible space.

```py
    class TestDetail(models.Model):
        ...
        def __str__(self):
            return ''
```